Adding a column to a dataset doesn't work when function has a warning
I have the following dataset:
data = {<|"col1" -> 1, "col2" -> 0.249|>, <|"col1" -> 3, 
    "col2" -> 0.406|>, <|"col1" -> 5, "col2" -> 0.018|>};
ds = Dataset[data]


I now want to add a third column, which its values are based on this interpolation:
interpolation = Interpolation[{
   {2, 13},
   {3, -4},
   {4, 7},
   {5, 11}
   }]

As suggested in this answer, I tried to do
ds[All, <|#, "col3" -> interpolation[#col1]|> &]

but nothing is evaluated; I get the warning

Input value {1} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will  be used.

Indeed, WL needs to extrapolate to get the value of interpolation[1], but when evaluated as a single instruction, a numerical values is returned:
interpolation[1] // N
(*93*)

Any idea how I can force the evaluation and get a dataset with "col3"?

Just use ds[All, <|#, "col3" -> Quiet @ interpolation[#col1]|> &] if you just want to suppress the message.

You may extend "interpolation" to eliminate the message:
interpolation = 
 Interpolation[{{1, Sin[1]}, {2, Sin[2]}, {3, Sin[3]}, {4, 
    Sin[4]}, {5, Sin[5]}}]

With this you get:
ds[All, <|#, "col3" -> interpolation[#col1]|> &]


Addendum
If extending the function is not an option, you can remove the message by:

Create the message: "... InterpolatingFunction: InputValue ...."
Click on the 3 dots at the beginning
Click on: "TurnOff This Message..."


I just gave as an example interploation of $\sin(x)$, but the case I am dealing with is very different. So I can't manually extend the range of the values in the interpolation. I edited the original question.

I added a description how to eliminate this message to my answer.

A simple Quiet is better than turning off the message completely.

@Sjoerd Smit  Have you tried it? Unfortunately it does not work.

Yes, I tried it. ds[All, <|#, "col3" -> Quiet @ interpolation[#col1]|> &] works for me. I'm guessing you tried putting Quiet on the outside? That won't work because Dataset will still see the messages internally.
